# Checking for specific command line arguments in C++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am building a CLI app that should do something similar to this:

```cpp
./app

Welcome to the app, Type -h or --help to learn more.

./app -h

list of commands:...
```

Here is the code i am trying to build:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)  {

   cout << "Welcome to the app. Type -h or --help to learn more\n";

   if(argv == "-h" || argv == "--help") {
      cout << "List of commands:...";
   }
  return 0;
}
```

But when i try to compile gcc gives following erros:

```
error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘char**’ and ‘const char*’ lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
    if(argv == "-h" || argv == "--help") {
               ^~~~
error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘char**’ and ‘const char*’ lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
    if(argv == "-h" || argv == "--help") {
                               ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: With e.g. `argv == "-h"` you compare two *pointers* that will never be equal. And the pointers are of different types as well, as mentioned in the error message. I suggest you [get a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read, as they should have information about what you want. There's also plenty of tutorials and examples on how to do it, if you just search a little.

Comment: Have a look at [`getopt()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt).

Comment: Assuming `-h` is the first command line argument - and you have checked `argc` to ensure such an argument is supplied - you need to do `strcmp(argv[1], "-h")`.   Better yet, instead of using C string comparison functions, work out how to use the C++ `std::string`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of C++17, the best way of writing this code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    using namespace std::literals;

    std::cout << "Welcome to the app. Type -h or --help to learn more\n";

    if (argv[0] == "-h"sv || argv[0] == "--help"sv) {
       std::cout << "List of commands:...";
    }
}
```

Prior to the existence of the `string_view` header you can use the `""s` `std::string` literal, which yields identical code to the above, just including the `string` standard header and changing `"…"sv` to `"…"s`. Such code unfortunately leads to redundant allocations but in this particular example that’s irrelevant.

Comment: How exactly can I use this without `using namespace std::literals`?

Comment: @HackerDaGreat57 You could use `using std::literals::operator ""sv;`, but don’t bother: `using namespace std::literals;` is the canonical solution. And this particular use of `using namespace` is acceptable even by organisations who otherwise never accept `using namespace`. If you want to avoid pulling all standard library literals into your scope, you can use `using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;`.

Answer (score 4):

argv is a pointer to char*.

You have to first chose which of the argc arguments you want to access.

e.g. argv[2] for the third argument.

And you can't do stringcompare with == on a char* you have to either use strcmp, or construct a string object from the char * like so:
string arg2 = argv[2];

then you can do arg2 == "--help"

Comment: `argv[2]` is the *second* argument, considering that `argv[0]` is the name of the command. And you should probably add a note to always check `argc` before indexing `argv`.

Comment: @A.Franzen argv[0] is always the name of the program/command and depending on the argc (Which contains number of parameters passed), you can access the corresponding parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the array of arguments and convert the char array to strings if you want to use the == operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)  {

    cout << "Welcome to the app. Type -h or --help to learn more\n";

    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        if(string(argv[i]) == "-h" || string(argv[i]) == "--help")
        {
            cout << "List of commands:...";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compare strings the way you compare integers !!!
use [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)/stricmp

Comment: C++ has much more readable ways of writing this code. Your assertion that “You cannot compare strings the way you compare integers” is simply false in C++ and doesn’t become more true if you add more exclamation marks.